# Civi won't take valid credit card number and verification number since upgrade to 4.7.24 - using PayPal Pro

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

Ever since upgrading to 4.7.24, transactions with PayPal Pro (in WP) generate the following error:

Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:

```
Please enter a valid Card Number
Please enter a valid Card Verification Number
```

The cc is valid and entered correctly on the Civi form.
Nothing is showing up in the Civi logs to clue me into what is happening.

- When using a PayPal account directly rather than entering cc info on the civi page, transactions are processed correctly.
- Recurring transactions are still processing and showing as completed in Civi.

Edit: The occurs on both online contribution pages and registrations pages.
A donation is processed correctly when entered through the backend.
A correct CVV code has been entered.  Earlier I noticed no cc were selected (when it was working), so I selected all anyway, and it still doesn't work on the front end.

Comment: Are you entering a CVV value?  Is there a place to enter a CVV value?  This is almost certainly related to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20264, but the more info you can give (by editing the original question) the quicker it can be resolved.  Which form, specifically, is this appearing on?

Comment: Could you please confirm from which form are you trying to do transactions? Are they Online Contribution pages or backoffice New Contribution form? And also could you please check Payment processor setting if the Card type for Card you entered is enabled for that payment processsor.

Comment: I couldn't replicate this - do you see an js errors? Do you only have one processor configured? Or multiple. Are you able to link to the page if it is a live page

Comment: Hey Karen: let's rule out Javascript errors on your front end pages -> can you swap the theme for a very boring one - and/or can you open up a Firebug Console -> reload the page -> and spot for Console errors as you fill it out.

Comment: There is only one payment processor configured.  There are some js errors BUT when in console entering cc no. get TypeError: card_values is undefined

Comment: Additional error info: TypeError: card_values is undefined[Learn More]  BillingBlock.js:76:13
 civicrm_billingblock_set_card_type/< https://.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.js:76:13
 each https://.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:2929
 civicrm_billingblock_set_card_type https://.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.js:74:5

Comment: civicrm_billingblock_creditcard_helper/</< https://.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.js:53:9
 dispatch https://.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:3:12392
 add/r.handle https://.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:3:9156

Comment: js errors are related to facebook